# Typescript type which returns different types in function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I am new to typescript and learning the concepts. While playing around, I was stuck in a scenario. There is a function called functonA which basically returns an object where the input to function has a response from an API.

```
type Combination = ResponseType1 | ResponseType2;

interface ResponseType1 {
  firstAttr: string,
  thirdAttr: string
}

interface ResponseType2 {
  secondAttr: string,
  thirdAttr: string
}

function someCondition() {
  return true // or false
}

function functionA(response: Combination) {
   return {
     ...(someCondition()) && { first: response.firstAttr }, // true condition
     ...(!someCondition()) && { second: response.secondAttr }, // false condition
     ...{ third: response.thirdAttr } // all case
   }
}
```

The problem here is I know that typescript can only type things based on the static analysis at build time. Initially I tried creating a type with Union of two Interfaces but failed miserably. I don't want to make fields optional in a single interface since that won't be a nice approach. API can return difference response key's based on some condition.

Now I am getting doesn't exists on type error since one of the keys is not there in other Interface.

Typescript version using: 3.0.1

Can somebody help me to find a solution for the same? please bear with me. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access a property if it is not common for all types if you use a union type.

What you can here is check for property before accessing it.:

```
type Combination = ResponseType1 | ResponseType2;

interface ResponseType1 {
  firstAttr: string,
  thirdAttr: string
}

interface ResponseType2 {
  secondAttr: string,
  thirdAttr: string
}

function someCondition() {
  return true // or false
}

function functionA(response: Combination) {
   return {
     ...(someCondition()) && { first: ('firstAttr' in response ? response.firstAttr: undefined) }, // true condition
     ...(!someCondition()) && { second: ('secondAttr' in response ? response.secondAttr: undefined) }, // false condition
     ...{ third: response.thirdAttr } // all case
   }
}
```

you can check the documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), and especially you can check the part called [working with union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types)

Comment: So this is the only possible way to check right? In this case API response might have more than 30 keys which may vary based on the condition.

Comment: Yes this is the only way as the documentations are indicating also.